# chkdsk unable to free space on corrupted RAID 0 partition

Tags: windows-7, disk-space, chkdsk, raid-0

I have a two 1TB SATA drives configured in RAID 0.  The partition is showing as 100% full despite only containing several hundred gigabytes of data.  When Windows boots, chkdsk attempts to automatically run each time.  I have had to walk away from the machine as the process appears to take several hours.  When I return, the only output I can see is a message saying cannot write to the log file.  I suspect this may be because there is no free space on the disk.

I have attempted to run chkdsk manually in Windows, but it appears to be locking up at 61%.  Is there a way to free this 'used space' without having to resort to a wipe and format of the partition?

```
C:\Windows\system32>chkdsk E: /X /I
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Volume dismounted.  All opened handles to this volume are now invalid.

WARNING!  I parameter specified.
Your drive may still be corrupt even after running CHKDSK.

CHKDSK is verifying files (stage 1 of 3)...
  142336 file records processed.
File verification completed.
  152 large file records processed.
  0 bad file records processed.
  0 EA records processed.
  0 reparse records processed.
CHKDSK is verifying indexes (stage 2 of 3)...
61 percent complete. (155299 of 155912 index entries processed)
Deleting index entry found.000 in index $I30 of file 5.
  155912 index entries processed.
Index verification completed.
CHKDSK is scanning unindexed files for reconnect to their original directory.
  5 unindexed files scanned.
CHKDSK is recovering remaining unindexed files.
61 percent complete. (3 of 45 unindexed files recovered)
```

Comment: Have you ruled out the possibility of a simple infection?

Comment: Unfortunately, avast! is not reporting any infection.

Comment: One suggestion on a Microsoft Tech forum suggested running a defrag.  Auslogics Disk Defrag is freezing on 61.20% the same as chkdsk.